# How to change the parameters of a pm2 process?

Tags: pm2

I would like to change some parameters of a pm2 process, particularly the `exec cwd` path since I am getting an error in the log that it cannot open the file but there is no error when launching the script from its folder .

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

`pm2` cannot start the process after I modified the related script to open a file in the same folder of the script. I see with `pm2 describe my-process` that the `exec cwd` is one-level-higher directory of the script directory so I am not assuming the file cannot be found for this reason.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you must try to launch script with admin permission (using `sudo`)

Comment: I don't think this is the case because before everything worked; `pm2` cannot start the process after I modified the related script to open a file in the same folder of the script. I see with `pm2 describe my-process` that the `exec cwd` is one-level-higher directory of the script directory.